# Execute function on startup

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, viewcontroller

I'm trying to develop an application for IOS using swift language that is a news for me. I want to fill a dictionary (tobaccoList) on the application startup. I have a csv file, so I take data from this file and than i fill the dictionary:

```
class DataManager{

var latitudes = Array<Double>()
var longitudes = Array<Double>()
var tobaccoList = Dictionary<Double, Tabacchino>()

init(){

    if let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/brunopistone/Developer/apptabacchi/LocationList_sorted.csv" , isDirectory: true) {
        var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
        if let csv = CSV(contentsOfURL: url, error: error) {

            //put every tabbacchino in a Dictionary tobaccoList
            let rows = csv.rows
            let totalRows = rows.count

            for var index = 1; index < totalRows; index++ {
                let temp = csv.rows[index]
                let tabacchino = Tabacchino(
                    name: temp["Name"]!, phone: temp["tnumber"]!, lat: NSString(string: temp["Latitude"]!).doubleValue, lon: NSString(string: temp["Longitude"]!).doubleValue
                )
                let keyGeo = NSString(string: temp["Latitude"]!).doubleValue
                storeTobaccoShop(keyGeo, value: tabacchino)

                var doubleLatitude = NSString(string: temp["Latitude"]!).doubleValue
                var doubleLongitude = NSString(string: temp["Longitude"]!).doubleValue
                storeLatitude(doubleLatitude)
                storeLongitudes(doubleLongitude)
            }
        }
    }
}

func storeTobaccoShop(key: Double, value: Tabacchino) {
    self.tobaccoList[key] = value
}
```

In the viewController file of the home page i have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let startFunction = DataManager()
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude = Double()
var longitude = Double()
var tobaccoList = Dictionary<Double, Tabacchino>()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    tobaccoList = startFunction.getTobaccoList()

}
```

In the home page, I have a button that calls another view, and i want to pass the dictionary to the other view in order to use it, so I use this method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "tobaccoListSegue"{

        let viewList = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewList
        viewList.tabacchini = tobaccoList
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i click on the button in order to call viewList, the application fills again the dictionary. What i want is to fill the dictionary only when I open the application.
Please help me fix this thing. Thanks

Comment: Are you creating a new`DataManager` anywhere else? Your code only shows it being created once. Unrelated but you are missing the call to super in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: No, what is related to DataManager it's done only in the piece of code that I wrote before

Comment: Your code shows that when a `DataManager` is created it parses the file. So if you create it twice you will end up loading the file twice. What does the code in `getTobaccoList()` look like?

Comment: `getTobaccoList( )` returns the dictionary that is created when the `DataManager( )` is initialized. I create a variable DataManager only one time, in `class ViewController`

Comment: What leads you to believe that the dictionary is being assigned multiple times?

Comment: @Paul.s when I click on the button in the home page in order to change view, the transaction is really slow (It seems that the app parses again all the csv file in order to fill the dictionary used in the other view, instead of copy as I wrote before `viewList.tabacchini = tobaccoList`

Comment: It seems that it is doing that or you have measured/logged it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line

```
let startFunction = DataManager()
```

Inside viewdidload() method.